# Oracle: Error ORA-02270 (no matching unique or primary key for this column-list)

Tags: sql, database, oracle, foreign-keys, create-table

I try to create 4 tables and link it together but it shows this error ORA-02270. How can I fix this? Is there any error when I declaring foreign and primary key that leads to this error.

```
CREATE table City (
    city_name VARCHAR(128),
    state_name VARCHAR(128),
    population number,
    elevation number,
    PRIMARY KEY (city_name, state_name),
    FOREIGN KEY (city_name) REFERENCES Mayor(city_name)
);

CREATE table State (
    state_name VARCHAR(128) PRIMARY KEY,
    region VARCHAR(128),
    FOREIGN KEY (state_name) REFERENCES City(state_name),
    FOREIGN KEY (state_name) REFERENCES Mayor(state_name),
    FOREIGN KEY (state_name) REFERENCES Governor(state_name)
);

CREATE table Mayor (
    mayor_name VARCHAR(128),
    city_name VARCHAR(128),
    state_name VARCHAR(128),
    party VARCHAR(128),
    PRIMARY KEY (mayor_name, city_name, state_name)
);

CREATE table Governor (
    governor_name VARCHAR(128),
    state_name VARCHAR(128),
    party VARCHAR(128),
    PRIMARY KEY (governor_name, state_name)
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your foreign keys are all mixed up, resulting in syntacically invalid relations. 
I understand the relationships as follows:

- a governor references a state
- a city refences a state
- a mayor references a city

Possibly, you should also have a `region` table, which the `state` table would reference.

Here is a new versin that is valid and implements the above relations:

```
CREATE table State (
    state_name VARCHAR(128) PRIMARY KEY,
    region VARCHAR(128)
);

CREATE table Governor (
    governor_name VARCHAR(128),
    state_name VARCHAR(128),
    party VARCHAR(128),
    PRIMARY KEY (governor_name, state_name),
    FOREIGN KEY (state_name) REFERENCES State(state_name)
);

CREATE table City (
    city_name VARCHAR(128),
    state_name VARCHAR(128),
    population number,
    elevation number,
    PRIMARY KEY (city_name, state_name),
    FOREIGN KEY (state_name) REFERENCES State(state_name)
);


CREATE table Mayor (
    mayor_name VARCHAR(128),
    city_name VARCHAR(128),
    state_name VARCHAR(128),
    party VARCHAR(128),
    PRIMARY KEY (mayor_name, city_name, state_name),
    FOREIGN KEY (state_name, city_name) REFERENCES City(state_name, city_name)
);
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=64529e1f82a6305d68a79cb8a6fa7c6e)**.